# Event change doesn't fire on dynamically populated Picker - Titanium SDK

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

I'm trying to create a custom Picker whose data is from a remote JSON. The problem is that it doesn't fire the 'change' event on the picker at the first time when I select a row from the picker, I have to close the picker and select a row from the picker again and then the event change works.

```
var clubs_data = [];
//custom object to handle the httpClient
new K().scoutmobile.Tools.getData(new K().scoutmobile.URL_BASE, {Accion:new K().scoutmobile.CLUBS}, function(_response){
    if(response.status.codigo === "RESULT"){
        clubs_data.push(Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'select a club'}));
        for(_j in _response.data){
            clubs_data.push(Ti.UI.createPickerRow({color:'#fff',title: _response.data[_j].Propiedades.club_nombre.Valor, id:_response.data[_j].Propiedades.club_id.Valor}));

        inputClubs.add(clubs_data); //where inputClubs is created previously

    }else{                              
        new K().scoutmobile.Tools.createDialog('invalid_user_alert_dialog_title','invalid_user_alert_dialog_message');
    }
});

//event listener
inputClubs.addEventListener('change', function(e){
        Ti.API.info(e.row.id);
    });

win.add(inputClubs);
```

In the Titanium Studio Console I get this:

```
[WARN][InputManagerService(   60)] Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@43f8dbb8
```

Any ideas what it is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I have three solutions for this, none of them are good enough:

1. A very stupid solution would be having picker pointing at empty option at start, then user need to change it anyways
2. If you loading another element of UI using that picker value, you can preload that part with the default (or first) option
3. You can modify Titanium SDK source code, where they write this log "Window already focused' and fire change event instead. This is pretty simple, I have done that for TabGroup control, it may take 2 hours of your time (either for Android or iOS)

Comment: Thanks what I could find a solution at appacelerator forums, just firing the change event before add the control to the window. http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/143754/event-change-doesnt-fire-on-dynamically-populated-picker---titanium-sdk